# How to order portable storage using SoftLayer API

Tags: storage, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there a simple method to order portable storage given the input datacenter such as WDC06 and size 500 GB.

At the moment the method I know of is painful, complex and manual, if I have do this in a new datacenter. First get the configuration through Product_Package and then going through long list of items to find the right product id, itemId ... etc. This call also requires that I should know the `pkgid` before hand.

`categories = client['Product_Package'].getConfiguration(id=pkgId, mask='isRequired, itemCategory.id, itemCategory.name, itemCategory.categoryCode')`

Please if you can share some code samples if this ordering process can be simplified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not idea how you are ordering the portable storage,but you need to use the [placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder/) method and get the proper prices for the disk size that you want to order, this literature can help you to understand how to make orders:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/location-based-pricing-and-you
https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-3

The process to pick the correct prices is hard, but you can use the object filters to get them:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters

and here a sample using the [softlayer Python client](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python):

```
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
API_USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

datacenter = "wdc06" # lower case
size = "500" # the size of the disk
diskDescription = "optional value"

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=API_USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
package = 198 # this package is always the same
# Using a filter to get the price for an especific disk size
# into an specific datacenter
filter = {
    "itemPrices": {
        "pricingLocationGroup": {
            "locations": {
                "name": {
                    "operation": datacenter
                }
            }
        },
        "item": {
            "capacity": {
                "operation": size
            }
        }
    }
}
price = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package'].getItemPrices(id=package, filter=filter)
# In case the request do not return any price we will look for the standard price
if not price:
   filter = {
    "itemPrices": {
        "locationGroupId": {
            "operation": "is null"
            },
        "item": {
            "capacity": {
                "operation": size
                }
            }
        }
    }
   price = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package'].getItemPrices(id=package, filter=filter)
if not price:
    print ("there is no a price for the selected datacenter %s and disk size %s" % (datacenter, size))
    sys.exit(0)

# getting the locationId for the order template
filter = {
    "regions": {
        "location": {
            "location": {
                "name": {
                    "operation": datacenter
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
location = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package'].getRegions(id=package, filter=filter)
# now we are creating the ordertemplate
orderTemplate = {
    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Disk_Image",
    "packageId": package,
    "location": location[0]["location"]["location"]["id"],
    "prices": [{"id": price[0]["id"]}],
    "diskDescription": diskDescription
}

#When you are ready to order change "verifyOrder" by "placeOrder"
order = client['SoftLayer_Product_Order'].verifyOrder(orderTemplate)
print order
```

Comment: Thank you, You answered my question and this is very helpful.

Comment: great, please  mark the answer as the correct and vote if the answer helped you :)